# Cardinality vs width in the ResNext architecture

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, convolution

I was recently reading the paper [Aggregated Residual Transformations for Deep Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.05431).

One thing the author mentions in **Section (5.1)** is that increasing the cardinality (or, the number of branches), decreases validation error more than increasing the bottleneck width or increasing the depth. I understand the depth part, but I'm a bit confused about the width. Isn't the cardinality of a residual block the same as the bottleneck width? If not, what is the difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in InceptionNet, which increases **width**, the different paths are **depth-concatenated** as well as each path is different (i.e different filter sizes for different paths).

While in ResNeXt, which increases **cardinality**, the different paths are merged by adding them together, and each path is similar.

Read this article for more information [An Overview of ResNet and its Variants](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-overview-of-resnet-and-its-variants-5281e2f56035)

Comment: Just to clarify: it seems that width is achieved by concatenating outputs from parallel branches, whereas cardinality is achieved by adding together outputs from parallel branches.